# Capture every match sentence with optional characters and words prefixed by a string

Tags: regex

How can I capture every match, with optional characters?

This is what I will have:

**keystring word**

**keystring word, word1, word2**

**keystring word, word1:BLUE, word2:RED**

I have an key string which will be in every sentence them one or multiple words separated by a `,` and sometimes they have an optional `:` followed by an upper-cased string value.

This is what I could capture so far:
https://regexr.com/3jdg1

Comment: `\w+(\:\w+)?` ?

Comment: So you just want to match strings that are separated by commas? What language do you use? What have you tried so far? Seems a pretty broad question to me...

Comment: @GalAbra edited!

Comment: @Trxplz0 in your examples every two words are separated not only by `,`, but by `' `. It's not clear what output do you want

Comment: (\w+(\:\w+)?(,\s)?)*

Comment: @D.Braun does match but miss the capture.

Comment: Like that?  /(\w+(\:\w+)?(,\s)?)*/replacement/  Sorry I have to go now.

Comment: @Trxplz0 Please check, if my answer satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
(\w+(:\w+|\s\w+?)?(,\s+)?)+
```

or if you know the keyword:

```
keystring\s(\w+(:\w+|\s\w+?)?(,\s+)?)+
```

You can try it [here (pythex.org)](https://pythex.org/?regex=keystring%5Cs(%5Cw%2B(%3A%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cs%5Cw%2B%3F)%3F(%2C%5Cs%2B)%3F)%2B&test_string=keystring%20word%0Akeystring%20word%2C%20word1%2C%20word2%0Akeystring%20word%2C%20word1%3ABLUE%2C%20word2%3ARED%0Akeystring%20word%2C%20word1%2C%20word2%3ARED%0Akeystring%20word%2C%20word1%2C%20word2%3ARED%2C%20word3%0A%0Atralala%2C%20hello%2C%2033%25&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

This should match hole lines like these ones:

```
keystring word
keystring word, word1, word2
keystring word, word1:BLUE, word2:RED
keystring word, word1, word2:RED
keystring word, word1, word2:RED, word3
```

and not lines like this one:

```
tralala, hello, 33
```

Comment: @Trxplz0 Please check my updated answer and if ti fits your requirements.

Comment: Glad I could help :)